# ckan minor upgrade from source git issue

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, ckan

I tried to do a minor upgrade from source on our CKAN installation. We currently have CKAN 2.2 running on a virtual environment on Ubuntu 14.04.
Due to bugs I want to upgrade the CKAN to version 2.5.2

I followed the recommended steps:http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/upgrading/upgrade-source.html

The git fetch worked ok and gave me:

```
From https://github.com/ckan/ckan
 * [new branch]      2.3.5-fix-solr-circleci -> origin/2.3.5-fix-solr-circleci
   9b3c01b..d0c8505  2933-test-faster -> origin/2933-test-faster
   b937f6a..e55dfca  master     -> origin/master
   6bba236..29c9aa2  release-v2.3.4 -> origin/release-v2.3.4
 * [new branch]      release-v2.3.5 -> origin/release-v2.3.5
   428c44e..7d2702f  release-v2.4.3 -> origin/release-v2.4.3
 * [new branch]      release-v2.4.4 -> origin/release-v2.4.4
   39a8901..1596665  release-v2.5.2 -> origin/release-v2.5.2
```

However running the checkout statement (git checkout release-v2.5.2) resulted in the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        ckan/config/solr/schema.xml
        ckan/i18n/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/ckan.mo
        ckan/i18n/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/ckan.po
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I have tried to find a solution online, but could not figure out what to do next. I also tried the following commands (no success):

```
git checkout -- release-v2.5.2
sudo git checkout -- release-v2.5.2
sudo git checkout -- origin/release-v2.5.2
```

Any links to manuals or other pointers much appreciated!!

Comment: It sounds like you changed those 3 files. Do you want to keep the changes or not?

Comment: Hi, yes I want to keep the changes and upgrade to newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command `git stash` to save the state of the files you've changed, do the `git checkout`, and then do a `git stash pop` to restore your changed files.

Comment: I tried this, was asked to set a default identity using 'git config'. This is the full error: 
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <myusername@servername>) not allowed
Cannot save the current index state

Comment: That sounds like a permissions error, which is weird. Have you tried omitting the `--global` option?

Comment: I ran the git config (using an existing email) - still same error as previous comment. And yes also without global and as sudo.

Comment: sudo git stash (after adding my email) DID work! Thanks TriskalJM